# Mapping an SQL View to a hibernate jpa Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've created a view in Postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tenant3.user_accounts AS 
 SELECT foo.c1
   FROM tenant3.dblink('dbname=genesis_admin'::text, 'SELECT username FROM user_account'::text) foo(c1 text);
```

I want to create a JPA entity that maps to this View so that I can query the said view using Spring Data JPA. is it possible? if so, how?

How would I map the said view to a Spring Data JPA Entity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to map views to JPA entities. After all, JPA does not distinguish between tables and views. Just make sure that the view has a "primary key" (a column or a group of columns that are not null and identify the row).

If you don't want the entity to be read only, add the appropriate rules and/or triggers.